# Is it possible to control order of script's parameters binding?

Tags: powershell

I was not able to figure out if the following is possible. Looks like it is not but thought I would ask community.

Let's say I have simple handling of script parameters, like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [parameter(Position=0)]
  [string] version,

  [parameter(Position=1)]
  [ValidateScript( { SomeModule/Search(version, $_); $true # FIND THIS VERSION IN SOURCE. **VERSION MUST HAVE BEEN SET BY NOW** } )]
  [string] source,
)
```

Now we can say '*version*' represents component's version and '*source*' represents some source (location) to search for that component (could be multiple sources). The earliest I can actually call search(source, version) is in the *ValidateScript{}* and this is good. It will not proceed with processing other parameters in the case some error happens in search(...). It also eliminates a bunch of *if(...){}* statements later in the code that otherwise would be necessary to check whether a parameter was passed and then run some action on it. However, the order of supplied values is important:

This is fine. Values are supplied in the right order

```
MyScript.ps1 -version 12345ABC -source 'filesystem'
```

This is fine. Values are supplied in the right order. Positional binding is in effect.

```
MyScript.ps1 12345ABC 'filesystem'
```

This is will not work. Values are supplied in the wrong (from scripts' logic point of view) order

```
MyScript.ps1 -source 'filesystem' -version 12345ABC
```

I do not want to put a restriction on client requiring specific order when parameter name is used.

As a work around I could re-arrange $ARGS but I cannot have any code prior to [CmdletBinding]. I could have a new script that would change the order in $ARGS and then call MyScript.ps1. Though this wouldn't be a nice solution. I am using PS 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Named parameters can be in any order as they are not bound by `Position`.

In your script these two **are** interchangeable as they are named parameters.

```
MyScript.ps1 -version 12345ABC -source 'filesystem'

MyScript.ps1 -source 'filesystem' -version 12345ABC
```

Positional parameters are not explicitly named, and do need to be in the correct order as defined by `Position` in your params.

```
MyScript.ps1 12345ABC 'filesystem'
```

Comment: I would like to call it like: -source 'filesystem' -version 12345ABC but have PS process -version first.

Comment: So if I understand from the other comments... your issue is actually with `ValidateScript`, if you don't specify version before filesystem the script doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. Because ValidateScript for source expects version being set already

Comment: Looks like you've found one of those weird things that powershell does when processing params. To my knowledge there's no way around this. ValidateScript is really for validating only a single parameter. You'd be best putting your tests into a function and calling it first. Something like this `if (Test-SourceAndFilesystem $version $filesystem) {throw "Failed Validation"}`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that you are trying to use one parameter in the other's validation script, and PowerShell appears to do the validate on invocation parse rather than actual execution. If you move the validation for $source into the body of the function, you will probably not have any further problem. I have not as yet tried this, but will when I get a chance, and will comment to confirm at that time.

Comment: (I am assuming that the OP has in fact tried this and found that it works [or doesn't] as described in the question. If this hasn't actually been tried, please try it before asking the question in the future.)

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, you can omit the Position declarations completely and powershell will process them as positional in order if you don't specify the parameter name (-name) on the command line.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [string] version,
  [ValidateScript( { SomeModule/Search(version, $_); $true # FIND THIS VERSION IN SOURCE. **VERSION MUST HAVE BEEN SET BY NOW** } )]
  [string] source,
)
```

At this point the following should work:

```
MyScript.ps1 12345ABC 'filesystem'
```

And also this should work:

```
MyScript.ps1 -source 'filesystem' -version 12345AB
```